How to compare count of two grouped column values in the DataFrame?
I have a dataset that looks like below:



Review
recommendation
game_name




Review...good
Recommended
Game 1


Review...bad
Not Recommended
Game 1


worst game
Not Recommended
Game 1


Review...Not Recommended
Not Recommended
Game 1


Review...awesome
Recommended
Game 2


Review...the game is okay
Not Recommended
Game 2


Review...the game is not fun
Not Recommended
Game 2


amazing
Recommended
Game 2


Good game..it's recommended
Recommended
Game 3


Review...good
Recommended
Game 3


Review...good
Recommended
Game 3



I intend to summarize the table by counting the occurrence of each "Recommended" and "Not Recommended" for each game on the basis of below condition:
IF Count(Recommended) > = Count(Not Recommended) THEN OUTPUT Recommended
IF Count(Recommended) < Count(Not Recommended) THEN OUTPUT Not Recommended
The final output that I am expecting is a new dataframe or the modified dataframe that looks like below:



Is_Recommended
game_name




Not Recommended
Game 1


Recommended
Game 2


Recommended
Game 3



I tried below groupby statement but I am unsure as to how I should proceed futher:
df['recommended'] = df.groupby(['game_name','recommendation'])['recommendation'].transform('count')


You can use crosstab to get the number of each value, after that use idxmax with axis=1 to get the column name who has the highest value.
Also use sort_index to sort the columns because idxmax will take the first column if the values are equal and Not Recommended was the first column without sorting, which is not the result we want since you want the value Recommended to take priority if the values are equal.
new_df = (pd.crosstab(df['Game Name'], df['Recommendation'])
          .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
          .idxmax(axis=1)
          .reset_index(name='Recommendation'))

  Game Name   Recommendation
0    Game 1  Not Recommended
1    Game 2      Recommended
2    Game 3      Recommended


You could use a mode in groupby.agg after converting to Categorical to ensure the desired order in case of a tie:
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['Recommended', 'Not Recommended'], ordered=True)

out = (df['recommendation'].astype(cat)
       .groupby(df['game_name'])
       .agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0]).reset_index()
      )

Another option would be to assign 1 to Recommended, 0 to Not Recommended and to get thegroupby.mean. Then assign the output values based on a threshold (here ≥0.5 but you could actually use any value).
out = (df['recommendation'].eq('Recommended')
       .groupby(df['game_name']).mean().ge(0.5)
       .map({True: 'Recommended', False: 'Not Recommended'})
       .reset_index()
      )

Finally, an alternative without groupby based on value_counts:
tmp = df[['recommendation', 'game_name']].value_counts()
out = (tmp.loc['Recommended'].ge(tmp.loc['Not Recommended'], fill_value=0)
       .map({True: 'Recommended', False: 'Not Recommended'})
       .reset_index(name='recommendation')
      )

Output:
  game_name   recommendation
0    Game 1  Not Recommended
1    Game 2      Recommended
2    Game 3      Recommended

